# Join two tables on one column and if not possible on second column

Tags: mariadb

### Preface

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE `permissions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL,
  `orders_and_returns` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `transactions` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `access_level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Permissions table have two kinds of rows, one is a profile

```
INSERT INTO permissions (`id`, `user`, `name`, `orders_and_returns`) VALUES (1, NULL, 'Admin', 1);
```

This means that there is a profile called **Admin**, which grants permissions to view orders. Any user with `access_level = 1` is an admin and can view orders.

The table also have a second kind of row

```
INSERT INTO permissions (`id`, `user`, `name`, `orders_and_returns`) VALUES (2, 2, NULL, 0);
```

This is a user specific permission. The user (`id = 2`) may have `access_level = 1` but there is an override for this user which revokes the access to orders. This is the row that must be used to determine their permission.

### Problem

I need to load the permissions for all the users in my table. So when I'm joining permissions table on user, I basically want to see if I can join on `users.id = permissions.user` (meaning user specific override is present) and if not I want to join with `users.access_level = permissions.id`. I'm not sure how to do this.

It may be possible with two queries like below but excluding all the results from second query that are in first query

```
1. SELECT email FROM users u JOIN permissions p ON u.id = p.user
2. SELECT email FROM users u JOIN permissions p ON u.access_level = p.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated 2022-03-20**

> hank will also have access_level = 1 meaning the profile is admin. But there is an override for it. The access_level value is not changed in the users table. With that change, your query returns 2 results for hank ; the profile and the override.

If records have both a profiled and access_level, you'll need to first rank the results (by overrides first) and then return the 1st result only:

```
WITH cte AS(
  SELECT 
     email
     , IF(u.id = p.user
         , 'user specific override'
         , 'profile' 
     ) AS PermissionType
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY u.id
        ORDER BY IF(u.id = p.user, 0, 1)
     ) AS RowNum
  FROM users u
        INNER JOIN permissions p ON u.id = p.user OR u.access_level = p.id
) 
SELECT *
FROM.  cte
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

**Results:**

> ```
> email           | PermissionType         | RowNum
> :-------------- | :--------------------- | -----:
> john@examle.com | profile                |      1
> hank@examle.com | user specific override |      1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=0fe45320ea016d02b2ccdddb20c46966)*

---

**Original Answer**

Have you tried a simple OR

```
SELECT email, IF(u.id = p.user, 'user specific override', 'profile')
FROM  users u 
        INNER JOIN permissions p ON u.id = p.user OR u.access_level = p.id
```

**Results:**

> ```
> email           | IF(u.id = p.user, 'user specific override', 'profile')
> :-------------- | :-----------------------------------------------------
> john@examle.com | profile                                               
> hank@examle.com | user specific override
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=f12e47f80b5bb8f250fae6ba410731fc)*

Comment: hank will also have `access_level = 1` meaning the profile is admin. But there is an override for it. The access_level value is not changed in the users table. With that change, your query returns 2 results for hank ; the profile and the override. Can you modify this somehow to get the override only? I've never seen a query like this. It'd be a beautiful solution if it works.

Comment: (Edit) I don't know what the data would like in that scenario. Could you post updated sample data, using this as a base? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=f12e47f80b5bb8f250fae6ba410731fc

Comment: Check this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=415607ebf722994156e3de2430ffd99b

Comment: Try this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=0fe45320ea016d02b2ccdddb20c46966

Comment: Works! Thanks. Update your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Great! Updated.